# TSQL - nested case

Tags: t-sql, case

I ask if the nested houses are used as follows:

```
SELECT
      CASE  
             WHEN Col1 < 2 THEN  
                                         CASE Col2 
                                                WHEN 'X' THEN 10 
                                                ELSE 11 
                                         END
              WHEN Col1 = 2 THEN 2
              .....
             ELSE 0 
      END as Qty,
      ......,
 FROM ....
```

explanation: If Col1 <2 shows something, but that something if X gives me the value 10 otherwise 11 If Col1 = 2 shows 2 otherwise 0 everything in the column name Qty

Is the reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's should return what you say you need, but it's easier to read this way:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Col1 < 2 AND Col2 = 'X' THEN 10
        WHEN Col1 < 2 THEN 11
        WHEN Col1 = 2 THEN 2
              --.....
             ELSE 0 
      END AS Qty
FROM
    -- ...
```